# Pass a list to/from Kivy textinput dialog

Tags: python, list, kivy

I have a list to display to the user but I want to break each section to a separate textinput as it will make more sense that way. I then need to be able to capture those changes and update my variable.

I need to get the variables to display correctly `tlmanualreg` being `backgroundManualReg[0]` and on `closeit()` store the changes back to a list.

EDIT: Updated with bare bones popup project to test variable exchanging.

---

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
import json

Builder.load_string("""
<-MyPopup@Popup>:
    tlpos:tlpos
    tlmanualreg:tlmanualreg
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        Label:
            text: "Location"
        Label:
            text: "Dist from Center (mm)"
        Label:
            text: "Corners of sheet (for manual-align)"
        Label:
            text: "Top-Left:"
        TextInput:
            id: tlpos
            text: root.backgroundTLPOS
        TextInput:
            id: tlmanualreg
            text: root.backgroundTLManualReg
    Button:
        size_hint_y:.1
        text: 'Update Variables'
        on_press: root.closeit()
""")


class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        content = MyPopup()
        _popup = Popup(content=content, auto_dismiss=False)
        _popup.open()


class MyPopup(Popup):
    backgroundManualReg = [[551, 218], [3168, 319], [519, 1617], [3190, 1589]]
    backgroundTLPOS = StringProperty("[0, 0]")
    backgroundTLManualReg = StringProperty("[1,1],[2,2]")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.tlmanualreg.text = str([1, 1])
        self.backgroundTLManualReg = str(self.backgroundManualReg[0])

    def closeit(self):
        self.backgroundTLPOS = self.tlpos.text
        print("backgroundTLPOS: ", self.backgroundTLPOS)
        print("backgroundTLManualReg: ", self.ids.tlmanualreg.text)
        print("backgroundManualReg: ", self.backgroundManualReg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Displaying a list and then converting the user input back into a list without string casting to display (not a big deal) but then needing ast.literal_eval to get it back into a list. Seems conveluded to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, we are:

- Using dictionary. The key of the dictionary is use as Kivy widget's id and also as a reference to update the values.
- Dynamically adding widgets as per item (key, value) in the dictionary
- Retrieving data using `for child in reversed(self.container.children)` and `isinstance(child, TextInput)`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import ast

Builder.load_string("""

<HeaderCell@Label>
    text_size: self.size
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0.502, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyPopup>:
    title: 'My Popup'
    container: container

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            size_hint_y: 0.1

            HeaderCell:
                text: "Location"
            HeaderCell:
                text: "Dist from Center (mm)"
            HeaderCell:
                text: "Corners of sheet (for manual-align)"

        GridLayout:
            id: container
            cols:3

        Button:
            size_hint_y:.1
            text: 'Update Variables'
            on_press: root.closeit()
""")


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        _popup = MyPopup(auto_dismiss=False)
        _popup.open()


class MyPopup(Popup):
    backgroundTLPOS = StringProperty("[0, 0]")
    bgManualRegDict = DictProperty({'Top-Left': [551, 218], 'Top-Right': [3168, 319],
                                    'Bottom-Left': [519, 1617], 'Bottom-Right': [3190, 1589]})

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.populate_rows()

    def populate_rows(self):
        for key, value in self.bgManualRegDict.items():
            location = Label(text="{}:".format(key), valign="middle")
            location.bind(size=location.setter('text_size'))
            bgTLpos = TextInput(text="{}".format(self.backgroundTLPOS))
            bgTLmanualReg = TextInput(id="{}".format(key), text="{}".format(value))

            self.container.add_widget(location)
            self.container.add_widget(bgTLpos)
            self.container.add_widget(bgTLmanualReg)

    def closeit(self):
        print("\ncloseit:")

        for child in reversed(self.container.children):
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                if child.id in self.bgManualRegDict.keys():
                    print("\tid={0}, text={1}".format(child.id, child.text))
                    self.bgManualRegDict[child.id] = ast.literal_eval(child.text)

        print("\n\tself.bgManualRegDict=", self.bgManualRegDict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]